# Pop-up based on location (Specifically the UK)

Tags: javascript, popup, location

I have a very internationalised website, however I need to produce a pop-up specifically for our UK customers.

What I require is:

On page load: Is the user from the UK?

If yes then show div.

Else

Div remains hidden.

Comment: http://www.ip2country.net/ can map IP addresses to country of origin, with roughly 95% accuracy. They have a free download, although I'm not certain how it compares to their paid product.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using **freegeoip**.
Since you mentioned that you want to use plain JavaScript (not jQuery), you should use JSONP to get the country:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>UK localisation</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv" style="display:none">
    <h1>Kittens</h1>
</div>

<script>
    function toggleDiv(content) {
        console.log(content.country_code);
        if(content.country_code === 'GB')   //Or GBR, or UK, I'm not sure.
        {
            document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = "inline";
        }
        else
        {
            alert("You are not from UK, you are from " + content.country_code);
            document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    window.onload = function()
    {
        // create script element
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        // passing src with callback name
        script.src = 'http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=toggleDiv';
        // insert script to document and load content
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this api endpoint does not work anymore... does anyone have work around this?